# How to change C# Telerik radRibbonBar color?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-radribbonbar

[image]

I have change two parts color in Telerik radRibbonBar. But I can't find how to change the third row color. I can't find the param color setting. Please help me how to change the third row color. I have try it for more than one week.